# Orientation Method not working for iPhone plus devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, screen-orientation

Below mentioned orientation delegate method not calling in case of iOS plus devices(iPhone 8plus/7plus/6plus...)

My code for orientation methods is:

Note: Landscape right checkbox is unselected by default.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return NO;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation{
     return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}
```

**My info.plist file is:**

```
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
```

Please guide me on this issue.

Comment: Did you try on the real device?

Comment: Curious - why only support one of the two landscape orientations? Apple frowns on such actions.

Comment: Usually when dealing with iPhone * Plus devices, you'll want to ascertain what [trait collection](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitraitcollection) is being used. In landscape mode on these devices your horizontal trait will be `.regular`, and your vertical trait will be `.compact`. You can use these hints to adjust your UI accordingly.

It seems like you're trying to restrict the orientation of the application to landscape. I'm assuming this is because this is a game and not a standard application. In which case defining your supported orientations in your plist is enough.

Comment: I'd recommend inspecting your target in Xcode and verifying if Xcode recognises that the Portrait orientation is disabled for your application. This might provide a hint about a potential misconfiguration issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a notification on view

```
UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
```

and check if it comes in the method.

Also you are returning No in your `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification` method try returning YES.

Hope this helps. Do let me know if you need any more explanation. This approach has been worked for me.